# Does using QJSEngine have security implications for my application?

Tags: javascript, qt, qt5, qjsengine

I am using QJSEngine to let the user script custom data transforms in my application. I understand QJSEngine is not sandboxed and runs at the same privelege level as my application. Does this have security implications I need to worry about? I am not exposing any application objects to QJSEngine.

I tried a few things:

Opening a url:

```
window.open();
```

Reading a file:

```
new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Accessing the registry:

```
new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
```

None of these worked. So is there anything nasty a user can do from inside QJSEngine? If so, what?